# Tortoise SVN hook show changes

Tags: c#, svn, tortoisesvn, hook, pre-commit-hook

We are using TortoiseSVN to commit repository changes and I am writing a hook in C#, which gets the file changes made passed by the diff, etc to basically show commit information to the user.

Is it possible maybe using a plugin or something to output the the information to the user, as the only thing I managed to find is writing to `Console.Error.WriteLine` and is only shown when there is an error using `Environment.Exit(1)`.

Is there any other way to write to the TortoiseSVN Client? Maybe someone has used another way.

Attached also please find a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt6xI.png) of how the `Console.Error.WriteLine` displays on the client TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 1):

Any response sent back from a pre-commit hook script must be sent via `stderr` (or equivalent) and is treated as a non-successful result from the hook script, which will result in the commit being rejected.

If you need to communicate to the committer from the pre-commit hook script, you will need to do it via another means (IM, email, Slack bot, etc.).